# CakePHP password doesn't get hash

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP 2.1 and i am trying to do user registration, the password does not get hashed before saving in the database.

Do we need to have Auth for this to happen?.

Comment: I recommend using a behavior to keep the code DRY: dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake 2.x does not automatically hash your password for you, as explained here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout

This decision was made because auto hashing was too magical, and interfered with things like validation. So, a simple addition to `beforeSave` on your User model will solve the problem!